# find the start of a matched region (java regex)

Tags: java, regex

Suppose the string I am interested is similar to these `num3.a`, `num4.b`, etc.
(but I don't want it to match these `foo.num3.a`, `whatever.num2.b`)

I have this regex to match them `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\.]\\bnum(\\d*)(?=\\.)";`

Given this input string : `(num3.a)`

```
Matcher m = p.matcher("(num3.a)");
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.start()); // This would print 0 rather than 1  WHY?
```

How do I change the code so it prints `1` instead? (because `1` is the index of `n`, which is the start of my interested pattern)

Comment: You don't even initialize your matcher here

Comment: (well that is "implied" code!)

Comment: What are you trying to print? Are you trying to print the string offset where capture group 1 matched? I don't know how.

Comment: @OneTwoThree Now you changed your pattern. `[^\\.]` matches anything that is not a dot or a '\'. A `(` is neither of those, so it is matched.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the flaw. So how should I fix it? ie., how do I say "does not start with a dot AND is a whole word (the "num" is not part of anything)"?

Answer (score 3):

If you're interessted in num3.a you should expand your Group. The brackets indicate a group and can be used to address within your match.

`[^\\.]\\b(num\\d*)(?=\\.)`

then you can access the group with

`start(0)` and `end(0)`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(num\\d*\\.a)");
String input = "fffffffffffff(num3.a)fffffffffffffffffsdfsdf";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.start(0));
    System.out.println(input.substring(m.start(0), m.end(0)));
}
```

will output

```
14
num3.a
```

Comment: +1 That something so trivial can be so confusing to some is just amazing.

Comment: So, `m.start(n)`, `n` is the capture group then, where `0` is the default entire match?

Answer (score 0):

The method [`Matcher#regionStart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#regionStart%28%29)

> Reports the start index of this matcher's region.

This doesn't indicate the start of the match, only the start of the region that is checked for a match.

Use `find()` and `start()` to find the start of a match.

Now you changed your pattern. `[^\\.]` matches anything that is not a dot. A `(` is neither of those, so it is matched. The `(` is at index 0 in the given `String`.

Comment: @OneTwoThree How did you try it? What are you expecting?

Comment: @OneTwoThree It prints 1 for me.

Comment: `[^\\.]` pattern has nothing to do with ``\`` because ``\`` is also metacharacter in `[...]` (it is used to produce `\\d` for example) and require escaping.

Comment: BTW to write ``\`` in comment you just need to surround it with two `\`` :)

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, sorry I was looking at it literally, not as a string literal.

Comment: Unless I missed something, the OP's code string `"[^\\.]"` sends `[^\.]` to the engine, essentially `[.]`, in string form `"[.]"` as well.

Comment: @sln The String literal `[^\\.]` has a value of `[^\.]`. `\.` matches `.` literally. The `^` means everything but that. See [here](http://regex101.com/r/qH0bS6).

Comment: Thats what I just said. Ok, typo error on the `^`, but that wasn't the point. The point was, the engine sees onlly `[^.]`

Comment: @sln Then I missed the point :(. What was your comment about?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\,\\d*");
    String inpu = "Hotel Class : 5,106936 ";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inpu);

    if (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(inpu.substring(m.start(0), m.end(0)));
    }
```

The output is "5,106936"